# Unity 3D's component-based design model and race conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, race-condition

I'm having a bit of trouble with Unity 3D's Component-based design model.

Here's an example that demonstrates my problem:

```
class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    MyType entity;

    void Start() 
    {
        entity = (MyType)FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MyType)).First();
    }

    void MyMethod() 
    {
        var x = entity.SomeProperty; // <= NullReference exception
    }
}

// ....

var clone = (GameObject)Instantiate(original);
clone.GetComponent<MyComponent>().MyMethod();
```

Sometimes, not always though, `MyMethod` executes before `Start` so what I end up doing is move all the initializations I usually have in `Start` to `MyMethod` which is quite an ugly workaround:

```
    void Start() { }

    void MyMethod() 
    {
        entity = (MyType)FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MyType)).First();
        var x = entity.SomeProperty; // <= now it's fine.
    }
```

My question is, what is the correct way of working with this pattern (without a constructor)?

Comment: I asked the question both here and on the Unity Answers forum.  Is that disallowed, or?

Comment: When you put the same question in multiple places, without crosslinks, you get people wasting their time typing the same thing other people already did, instead of building on it.  You need to do your small part to push humanity forward by never doing this again and not accepting when others do it.

Comment: I pledge that from now on, I will never do this again and will not accept when others do it.  Thank you Jessy...

Comment: I'm proud of you.  Stupid site locked my vote, however.

Comment: Interestingly enough though, there was another downvote; didn't know people can get so angry in the absence of crosslinks.  Lesson learnt I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That probably happens when you call MyMethod from the Awake of another Component, because Awake is called [before the game starts](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Awake.html). The only solution I see is to make sure that you don't call methods on other components (in this case MyMethod) in the Awake() event, but rather in the Start() event.

Comment: Yea, so the problem was that didn't actually know that `Awake` is called before the game starts, and thus I had used it incorrectly in the past.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity documentation says "Awake is called before the game starts" but this is not precise. A component's Awake method is called when in a scene the *gameobject becomes active* which carries the component.

Some gameobjects will be active by default when a scene is loaded, but other gameobjects might be activated later. Then there is the possibility of dynamically adding components via AddComponent.

This aspect should be kept in mind when relying on dependencies between Awake and Start methods. Another example for a race condition is to enable a component from the Update method. While enabling a component implies that its Start method will be called, this will not happen in the running update cycle, so that other components cannot rely on the first component's ".enabled" property to determine wheter it has been started or not.